# Make a Java TcpListener available on Internet

Tags: java, sockets, hosting, tcp

I've created a Java TcpListener little application.
Now I want to make it available for the TcpClient, across the internet (for now, I used it locally only).
Which kind of service can help me host that? 
I'm familiar working with Web Server hosting, but for this I need the TCP/IP layer only, which I'm a novice at.

Thanks

Comment: Probably better asked at [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just run your application on a server (computer) which is connected to the Internet. And open the port you are listening to. So your clients can reach it via the IP and PORT dress. If you need to access via internet you will need a Public IP for your computer which is visible through the internet.

You do not need a web server for this (as for web hosting), but you need to check out many other security issues which come along.

Comment: Any recommended online vendors? I just don't know how to name this kind of hosting service (in comparison to simple Web Hosting).